# client.accept_invite won't work, account tries to join but instead it just hangs

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've tried doing 
`client.accept_invite("link of invite in discord.gg or url id(tried both many times)"`
but It doesn't seem to work, when I put the invite code in, it tries to join, the script just keeps hanging and nothing is happening, on the other hand, every time I tried to join the invite link I needed to reconfirm the email on the account, after I reconfirm it, I try again, and again I need to confirm it, and so on.
I've read the discord API and they still have accept_invite in their documentations, I don't see why this won't work? I've tried logging into the account with token AND email+pw, both give same results. No error, just hanging +  email needs to be reconfirmed.
If anyone knows how to help, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Client.accept_invite()` is
 a) deprecated
b) intended for user accounts
Additionally, logging in using email+pw flags your account and could result in punishments (thats the last I heard at least)
Do not use this, instead make a bot account and ask users to invite your bot through it's oauth URL.
Each time you use an endpoint you shouldnt (like the endpoint used to login with username and password), Discord unverifies and flags your account.

Comment: But then, why do they still have it in the latest API documentations? And yes, this is a user account, it doesn't have anything else except client.accept_invite(), I want to make it so, if my account is kicked from my own server it rejoins back (We've had problems before when a rogue admin started kicking other moderators and kicked my main which had perms compared to him just a lower role(also my main didn't host the server but it's my server))

Comment: @MainAkaunt Discord may have it in their documentation but what I have said still stands. The solution for this might be to be careful who you give admin to?

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info, but would you know why upon trying to join it asks me to confirm my account again, and again, over and over, even if I confimed it each time?

Comment: @MainAkaunt you're probably going to get banned if you've done it multiple times. Each time you use an endpoint you shouldnt (like the endpoint used to login with username and password), Discord unverifies and flags your account for "suspicious" behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

The [current version of the Discord API](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/invite#accept-invite) is pretty clear:

> This endpoint is deprecated and will be discontinued on March 23, 2018

Comment: It says that [Guild Add Member](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#add-guild-member) should be used instead, how would I do that?

Comment: @MainAkaunt that's for oauth applications, a completely different topic.

Comment: @necko How so? Doesn't it work same as accept_invite or? Should I make another question?

Comment: @MainAkaunt Open another. Look into OAuth2 with Discord first and then ask about what you have tried

Comment: @necko It won't allow me to post more posts at the moment, could you just explain to me how Guild Add Member works? Does it use an Invite to join a server same as accept_invite? Or what is the concept?

Comment: @MainAkaunt it uses OAuth2 to authenticate the user with an application